# Connecting to the LOXO API using JQUERY AJAX ....it doesn't work

Tags: jquery, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to connect to the LOXO Dashboard Platform using credentials they provided me. I am modifying a plugin designed to connect to this platform to inject information about candidates who wish to apply. Here is the jQuery AJAX script I am working on, but I am unable to pass the data through the API. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the script?

Script below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    // var usernamex = 'user name API';
     //var passwordx = 'Password API';

    // Base64 encode the username and password
   
    /* var name = $("#name").val();
     var phone = $("#phone").val();
     var email = $("#email").val();
     var resume = $("#resumeinput").val(); */

    /* var formdata = {
            name: 'Luis test',
            phone: '1-555-555-555',
            email: 'luiscabre@myemail.com',
            resume: 'resumeInput'
        };  */
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://loxo.co/api/kinetic-staffing/jobs/1596232/apply',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:   JSON.stringify(formData),
     beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64Credentials);
            },
    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
    processData: false,  
    contentType: 'application/json',  
    success: function(response) {
        applyJobBtn.attr("disabled", false);
        // Handle the server response
        jQuery('.wljap_job_form_wrap').find(".wljap_success").remove();
        jQuery('.wljap_job_form_wrap').find(".wljap_error").remove();
        if(jQuery.trim(response) == "success")
        jQuery('.wljap_job_form_wrap').prepend('<span class="wljap_success">Job Applied Successfully</span>');

    
        else
        jQuery('.wljap_job_form_wrap').prepend('<span class="wljap_error">'+response+'</span>');
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        // Handle errors
        //alert('Error submitting the form.');
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

HTML FORM to send the data

```
   <a href="#_" style="color:#2B85BB" class="apply_now" rel-id="<?php echo $jobDetail["id"]; ?>">Apply Now</a>
   <div class="wljap_job_applyform" style=" background-color:#fff; padding:20px; display:none">
    <div class="wljap_job_form_wrap">
        <form action="" method="POST" id="wljap_job_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="" id="apply_job_id" />
            <div class="wljap_job_form_fields">
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" />
            </div>

            <div class="wljap_job_form_fields">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" />
            </div>

            <div class="wljap_job_form_fields">
                <label>Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" />
            </div>

            <div class="wljap_job_form_fields">
                <label>Upload Resume:</label>
                <input type="file" name="resume" id="resumeInput" />
            </div>

            <div class="wljap_job_form_fields">
                
            <input type="submit" id="applyJob" value="Apply" />

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```